# Export constants from header with Cython

Tags: python, c, cython

I'm using Cython to wrap a C library. The C library's header file defines a number of constants, so in my cython module, I have something like:

```
cdef extern from "lib.h":
    cdef int CONST_A = 0
    cdef int CONST_B = 1
```

When I compile the extension, the constants are not available in Python. I tried doing something like this, but it did not seem to work:

```
cdef extern from "lib.h":
    cdef int CONST_A = 0
    cdef int CONST_B = 1

CONST_A = CONST_A
CONST_B = CONST_B
```

Any ideas on how to make these constants available in Python?

Comment: I think you might be able to use `cpdef` instead of `cdef` for the constants.

Comment: I tried that, it does not work.

Comment: https://github.com/cython/cython/commit/50133b5a91eea348eddaaad22a606a7fa1c7c457

Comment: Try answer of @Y.Kou . I guess you just have name collision.

Answer (score 5):

You're right in that there seems to be a hole in Cython there.

I can declare `cpdef int CONST_C = 3` and it compiles but isn't visible from Python.  That would seem to be a bug -- if it accepts the syntax, it should do something reasonable with it.

One thing that did seem to work is this:

```
cpdef enum:
    CONST_A = 0
    CONST_B = 1
```

That may or may not be good enough for your case, but it seems it would work well for many use-cases -- maybe it's why the bug wasn't noticed?

Answer (score 2):

The solution I use which would be fairly easy to then switch to the "right" solution once supported is to re-declare the enum values one by one in the .pyx file prefixed by the enum's name, then they are quite easy to spot.

So in foo.pxd:

```
cdef enum Mood:
    happy
    sad
```

Then in foo.pyx at global scope:

```
Mood_happy = happy
Mood_sad = sad
```

And in bar.py:

```
from foo import Mood_happy, Mood_sad

# do something with Mood_happy and Mood_sad as ints
```

Answer (score 2):

Too late comment but how about the following code ?
This idea is derived from [How can a #defined C value be exposed to Python in a Cython module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697479/how-can-a-defined-c-value-be-exposed-to-python-in-a-cython-module)

This solution works well in my library.
"CONST_A" and "CONST_B" are alias for cdef/cpdef functions.
In  of Cython(.pyx), they can be used as a macro.
To expose macro to Python, CONST_A = _CONST_A and CONST_B = _CONST_B are needed.

a.pyx

```
cdef extern from "lib.h":
    cdef int _CONST_A "CONST_A"
    cdef int _CONST_B "CONST_B"

def use_const():
    if CONST_A:
      do_something()
    if CONST_B:
      do_something()

CONST_A = _CONST_A
CONST_B = _CONST_B
```

After compile, you can use them in python code.

use_a.py

```
import a
print(a.CONST_A)
print(a.CONST_B)
```