# How To Import a Global Variable from C++ header to use in Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am working on a C++ project that needs to be wrapped in Cython to ultimately use in integration tests in Python. I have a global variable used to default a value in a function in my C++ header file that looks like

```
header file
const uint8_t kAudioLevel = 0x5a;
```

This is used in a function in the c++ files like

```
void func(uint audioLevel=kAudioLevel)
```

I am wrapping this function in Cython, and currently have another variable with the same name used in my .pyx file like

```
DEF kAudioLevel
```

This default value is passed into the func() wrapper in C++ to allow that value to be defaulted. However, I would really like to have this variable used in the wrapper be imported directly from the header file, so I have a single source of truth and dont have to change this variable twice every time. I have tried adding the following:

```
pxd file
cdef extern from "header.h":
cdef cppclass Class:
    int kAudioLevel
```

And then attempt to use kAudioLevel directly in the .pyx like so

```
def func(audioLevel = kAudioLevel):
return client.func(audioLevel)
```

This is to allow us to have the value be defaulted across Cython and C++, and not have to edit it twice. However, the variable is not found when I try this. Not sure if I have to add the header class to both the pxd and pyx files and how to do this. I looked over the Cython documentation but didnt find anything useful.

Comment: Maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766219/export-constants-from-header-with-cython

Answer (score 0):

For a `const` member like `cpy.hh`:

```cpp
#ifndef CPY_HH
#define CPY_HH

#include <cstdint>

const uint8_t kAudioLevel = 5;

#endif
```

with `cytest.pyx`:

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint8_t

cdef extern from "cpy.h":
    cdef uint8_t kAudioLevel
```

Allows me to use `kAudioLevel` within my `.pyx` file. With a `exposedKAudioLevel = kAudioLevel` I can expose this to outside the module.

If you wanted a truly global variable, that is a bit more complicated, but with `cpy.hh`:

```cpp
#ifndef CPY_HH
#define CPY_HH

#include <cstdint>

extern uint8_t kAudioLevel;

#endif
```

`cpy.cc`:

```cpp
#include "cpy.hh"

uint8_t kAudioLevel = 5;
```

and the same `cytest.pyx` as above, I could create a variable I could access and modify, from both `.pyx` and `.cc`.

Unfortunately `kAudioLevel` is not exposed to the outside importer, so to access/modify, helper functions would be needed, like `getVal()`, `setVal(newVal)`, as far as I saw.