# Translate headers to Cython

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, cython, header-files, include-guards

Is it feasible for Cython to have the ability to translate C headers Cython-directives? (See [here](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html), in Conditional Compilation).
A similar suggestion was made [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cython-users/1JWXwU-bjLY/SrpEC7PiIW8J) too.

In my case, I would like these C-directives in my .h:

```
/* myheader.h */
#define MONIT_STEP      1 // stuff for step monit
//#define MONIT_SCATTERING 1 // monitor particle scattering
#define clight          (3.0*1e10)  
//#define NORM(x,y,z)  (sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)) // maybe this is too much to ask?
```

to be translated to:

```
# cython_header.pyx
DEF MONIT_STEP   = 1
DEF clight       = (3.0*1e10)
```

So that later, I can do:

```
include "cython_header.pyx"
```

in any other `.pyx` code I want to compile.
Of course, I'm implying to have the hability to ignore any character after any "//" string in the `myheader.h`.

I left the `NORM(x,y,z)` commented as I don't see it trivial to implement, due to its "function" nature (i.e. it's not just copy-paste).

I thought I could catch the C-preprocessor with this (see Cython docs, in "Referencing C header files"):

```
cdef extern from "spam.h":
    pass
```

but doesn't work.

---

Of course, I can always use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697479/how-can-a-defined-c-value-be-exposed-to-python-in-a-cython-module) method, but I'm hoping we can be more consistent.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just try this?

Comment: There is no automated header translator. The method in the answer you linked right at the bottom is the right way. If you only need to use them from Cython and not Python you can just use the `cdef extern` block without re-assigning them. `NORM` can be defined as if it was a function instead of a macro.

Comment: Ok, I was just checking if the cython compiler made any progress in this direction, since that method is from 2011. Thanks for your comments!